# Creating an Eclipse Color Theme for a non-Java language

Tags: eclipse

When defining an Eclipse Color Theme, various keywords are used to define the colors. Keywords like:

staticFinalField
javadoc
abstractMethod

Some of the keywords are fairly generic but there really doesn't seem to be much support for other languages in terms of how they name their tokens. For example, Python defines "literals" and "delimiters" but it's not clear what these map to in Eclipse Color Theme. Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Defining a color theme using what?